# ios не подгружает css файлы для сайта

Tags: css, ios, safari

Ребят, запутался совершенно, в браузере все норм. на мобилке отлично работает, safari не подключает ни одного стиля, как быть?)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" /> 
<activity ios:name=".SomeActivity" ios:label="@string/app_name" ios:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: было бы неплохо видеть ваш код...

Comment: Вы уверены, что адреса правильные? Попробуйте указать по другому )

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity ios:name=".SomeActivity"
              ios:label="@string/app_name"
              ios:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: вот как то так , бутстрап и прочее подключаются по ссылкам

Comment: пробывали писать как то так `href="../css/style.css">`

Comment: нашел еще одну тонкость, не подключается именно первый стиль

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">     в моем случае

Comment: вы указываете адреса относительно вашего Html файла?

Comment: проблему с загрузкой я решил, теперь проблема в том, что он их не пременяет